# Print ASCII of a triangle shape with variable input

Tags: c#, console-application

Struggling with the print. I know it should be two for loops to print out the repeated letters, however, having problems to indent the lines. it should be a simple console C# program to print out the shape like below with a input 3.

```
XXXXX
 XXX
  X
```

With input 4 it should be like

```
XXXXXXX
 XXXXX
  XXX
   X
```

Here is my code. Two for loops get the letters correctly but the lines all lined up at the left, not center.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string num = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(num);
        int k=1;
        for(int i = n; i>=1; i--)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(n));
            for (int j = (2*i-1); j>=1;j--)
            {                   
                    Console.Write("0");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, at least put your code here, not only actual result and expected one.. however, once you post your code, some people still does not eager to answer you, due to.. as usual *we in stackoverflow is not code generator*. if its for debugging, you might want to ask in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, two for loops get the letters correctly but the lines all lined up at the left, not center.

Comment: PadLeft(n) won't work because the space is not fixed.

Comment: The space is not fixed. So the number k should be a variable in PadLeft(k).

Comment: @BagusTesa Code Review only accepts working code, so you definitely should not ask a debugging question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(n));
```

is the right *idea* but it's not quite there.

In your case, `n` is the number of lines you wish to print and is invariant. The number of spaces you need at the start of each line should begin at zero and increase by one for each line.

In any case, printing *any* number of spaces followed by newline (because it's `WriteLine`) is not what you want, you should be using `Write` instead.

So the code between int `n = Convert.ToInt32(num);` and `Console.Read();` would be better off as something like:

```
for (int lineNum = 0; lineNum < n; lineNum++) {
    int spaceCount = lineNum;
    int xCount = (n - lineNum) * 2 - 1;

    Console.Write("".PadLeft(spaceCount));
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(xCount, 'X'));
}
```

You'll notice some other changes there. First, I've used more meaningful variable names, something I'm a bit of a stickler for - using `i` is okay in certain circumstances but I often find it's more readable to use descriptive names.

I've also used `PadLeft` to do the `X` string as well, so as to remove the need for an inner loop.